# unable to print values of custom jsp tag <% %>

Tags: jsp, tags, xhtml

I have a problem with printing a variable in Jsp custom tags. When using this below code, c:out does not print anything and when trying to use the default attribute in c:out, it prints the value in default which means that the variable is *null* which it is not here is my code.

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <% int x = 1;%>
 <c:out value="${x}" />
```

HOw can i make this Work

Comment: what is the output that you get ? do you get `${x}` ?

Comment: nothing (blank page)

Comment: let me know if you still have the same problem, after using the solution i posted below

Comment: x is a scripting variable. In order to use it as a scoped variable, you must put it into a scope.

Comment: Here is one way. <c:set var="x" value="<%=x%>" />

Comment: Or do it in the scriptlet.  pageContext.setAttribute("x", x);

Comment: Thanks @rickz its working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print a declared variable in `scriptlet` tag, using `c:out`
tag, then you can do it in the below mentioned way

*Set the variable in the page context under a variable name and evaluated the value using EL expressions*

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<%
   int x = 1;
  //set variable x in the page context under the variable name "var_x"
  pageContext.setAttribute("var_x",x);
%>
<c:out value="${var_x}" />
</body>
</html>
```

For more details you can view this tutorial [The most commonly used JSTL tag which is used to display the result of the expressions](http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/jstl/jstl-core-tag-out)

Comment: Thanks that's Worked for me